# Question posted under wrong user number

Tags: support

I'm user 929690 on "stackoverflow".  But somehow when I logged into "mathematics" list yesterday it set up an anonymous account under user number 30849.  I was then later able to log into "mathematics" with a user number of 30851 that showed my correct bio and now showed up on my "stackoverflow" page.  Can the question posted under "mathematics" user number 30849 be transfered to user number 30851 Harry Spier.

Comment: I have flagged this for moderator attention. For future reference, there's a "contact us" link at the bottom of the m.se front page, and that's the way to go when you have something only the moderators can do something about.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The "contact us" email goes to SE staff, not site moderators. Flagging (or possibly posting in chat) is the best way to get hold of diamond moderators for stuff like this that doesn't necessarily require employee involvement.

Answer (score 4):

I did some creative shuffling, and everything should be sorted out now: [here is the new location of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142886/formula-for-straight-part-of-a-slightly-bumpy-line), and it is now owned by your account. The 3 votes you received on your question were cleared unfortunately, but I've given the new version of the question a +1.

Comment: wouldn't merging users 30849 and 30851 have done it?

Comment: User 30849 was deleted already (I'm not aware of how), so that wasn't possible.